# SQL - product review scores weighted for user type

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a product review scenario where we have two levels of user, senior and junior. The senior users reviews should be weighted twice as important as the junior users reviews. If a senior user reviews a product 10 and a junior user reviews it 1 then the score will be ((10x2) + 1) / 3 = 7.

Can anyone help me craft some SQL to do this? I'm using MySQL 5.5.

Here's a sample database

```
create database products;
use products;
CREATE TABLE Product (ProductID int(10)  AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(20), primary key(ProductID));
CREATE TABLE Review (ReviewID int AUTO_INCREMENT, ProductID int, UserID int, performanceScore int, valueScore int, primary key(ReviewID));
CREATE TABLE User (UserId int AUTO_INCREMENT, StateID int, name varchar(20), primary key(UserId));
insert into product values (1, 'car1'), (2, 'car2'), (3, 'car3');
insert into review values (1, 1, 1, 10, 10), (2, 1, 2, 1, 1), (3, 1, 3, 5, 5), (4, 2, 1, 5, 5);
insert into user values (1, 2, 'SENIOR'), (2, 1, 'JUNIOR'), (3, 0, 'INACTIVE');
// NB: three reviews of car 1, one by an senior user (stateid 2), one by junior user (stateid 1), one by inactive user
```

Here's some code that does the calculation but not weighted

```
SELECT p.*, SUM(CASE WHEN u.stateID NOT IN (1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS reviewCount,
CASE WHEN u.stateID >= 1 THEN (avg(r.performanceScore) + avg(r.valueScore))/2 ELSE NULL END as score
FROM product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN review r ON p.ProductID = r.ProductId
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.userId = r.userId
GROUP BY p.ProductID
```

The pseudocode would be something like this

```
$score = 
  (
    if (user.stateID = SENIOR) 2xperformanceScore + 2*valueScore
    if (user.stateID = JUNIOR) performanceScore + valueScore
  )
  / (2xSeniorUser + 1xJuniorUsers)
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I think you can write it almost as you have it - select case when a then x when b then y end ...

Comment: I couldn't quite figure out the syntax, but I'll have another crack thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do:
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01439/1)

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT p.*, SUM(CASE WHEN u.stateID NOT IN (1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS reviewCount,
GROUP_CONCAT(r.performanceScore) performanceScore, -- this is just for your information
GROUP_CONCAT(r.valueScore) valueScore,             -- this is just for your information
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE u.name WHEN 'SENIOR' THEN 2 WHEN 'JUNIOR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) users, -- this is just for your information
SUM((r.performanceScore + r.valueScore) * CASE u.name WHEN 'SENIOR' THEN 2.0 WHEN 'JUNIOR' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END)/
SUM(CASE u.name WHEN 'SENIOR' THEN 2 WHEN 'JUNIOR' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)as score
FROM product p
LEFT OUTER JOIN review r ON p.ProductID = r.ProductId
LEFT JOIN user u ON u.userId = r.userId
GROUP BY p.ProductID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01439/1/0)**:

```
| PRODUCTID | NAME | REVIEWCOUNT | PERFORMANCESCORE | VALUESCORE | USERS |    SCORE |
|-----------|------|-------------|------------------|------------|-------|----------|
|         1 | car1 |           2 |           6,10,1 |     5,10,2 | 0,2,1 | 14.33333 |
|         2 | car2 |           1 |                5 |          5 |     2 |       10 |
|         3 | car3 |           0 |           (null) |     (null) |     0 |   (null) |
```

Comment: That looks pretty awesome, thanks @cha! I guess if I want it out of ten I just change it to "(r.performanceScore + r.valueScore)/2" so the performance and value scores are equally weighted? And if I think performance is more important than value say "(r.performanceScore*3 + r.valueScore) / 4"?